# Draw OpenStreetMap items on svg

Tags: javascript, svg, openstreetmap

The areas from OpenStreetMap are converted into an array which contains coordinates of all areas to draw on the SVG in the browser.

```
[
  "48.2290963 16.3522533",
  "48.2294087 16.3521388",
  "48.2294249 16.3525140",
  "48.2297088 16.3523572",
  "48.2298889 16.3523674",
  "48.2299063 16.3528332",
  "48.2293137 16.3529256",
  "48.2293106 16.3525268",
  "48.2291061 16.3525292",
  "48.2291009 16.3523838",
  "48.2290963 16.3522533"
]
```

The array contains all vertices of the area (First element of each subarray is the x coordinate, second one is y).

If I generate an `<svg>` with `<polygons>` where the `points=""` attribute is filled with the values of the array above, nothing's visible, which is logical:

The numbers are very high and only differ in the last decimal places.

In order to render visible, well-scaled areas, I would have to strip the "empty miles" at the sides of the map data.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different options:

- use the `viewBox` attribute on the `svg` element, e.g. `viewBox="48.229 16.352 0.001 0.001"` (NB: Safari seems to have a bit of an issue with very small widths such as these)
- use a `transform` with the appropriate `translate` and `scale`
- convert the coordinates before generating the polygon. `-` and `*` should be enough for this.